# Karate.match using contains throws reference error when used inside a javascript function

Tags: karate

I wanted to compare text results for a UI scenario for different click operations and used similar to below function in my script under the background section. But I am getting "reference error 'actualText' is not defined". Cant I use the karate.match and perform contains operation?.
`

```
function(action, actualText, expText){
var result;
if(action= 'test1'){
expText = expText + 'ABC';
result = karate.match("actualText contains expText").pass;
> }
else if(action = 'test2'){
expText = expText + 'DEF';
result = karate.match("actualText contains expText").pass;
> }
else if(action = 'test3'){
expText = expText + 'GHI';
result = karate.match("actualText contains expText").pass;
> }
return result;
> }
```

`

Karate.match does not work with contains operation inside javascript function.

Comment: saw your kind comments in the answer you posted Vijay, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Since it is a simple comparison, just use JS:

```
result = actualText.includes(expText);
```

Personally I feel writing a function for this is overkill.